# Insert multi lines after match using Mac's sed command

Tags: sed, osx

I have 2 files:-

**a.xml**

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        ...
    </parent>
</project>
```

**b.xml**

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
</project>
```

I want to copy `<parent>...</parent>` from a.xml and place it after `</modelVersion>` in b.xml:-

This is what I have:-

```
PARENT=`awk '/<parent>/,/<\/parent>/' a.xml | tr '\n' ' '`
sed -i '' "s|</modelVersion>|</modelVersion> ${PARENT}|g" "b.xml"
```

While it works, it looks rather unformatted because I have to replace the line break with space to prevent `sed` from complaining about unescaped line breaks.

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>     <parent>         ...     </parent> 
</project>
```

How do I make b.xml looks like this?

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        ...
    </parent>
</project>
```

I'm using Mac, by the way.

Comment: How many times? I mean, is there only the one `<parent>...</parent>` block and only the one `</modelversion>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. I take some pains to *only* affect the first occurence of either `<parent>...</parent>` and `</modelVersion> *$` - else it could be made more simple. It also escapes all `a`ppended characters correctly just in case.

```sh
sed -e'/^ *<parent>/!d;:n'      \
    -e'$d;N;/\n *<.parent>/!bn' \
    -e's/[\[:space:]]/\\&/g'    \
    -e's|.*\(.\n\)|/<.modelVersion> *$/a\1&|;q' a.xml |
sed -e'1,/<\/modelVersion> *$/{' -f- -e\}       b.xml
```

I'm not 100% sure that the BSD `sed` will recognize `-` to mean stdin. If I recall correctly it *does*, but, just in case, you can replace the `-f-` with the switch and argument `-f/dev/fd/0` if you must.

Here is the script the first `sed` writes to the second `sed`'s stdin:

```
/<.modelVersion> *$/a\
\ \ \ \ <parent>\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ...\
\ \ \ \ </parent>
```

And when the second `sed` matches the first `</modelVersion> *$` in input it appends the string to look like:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        ...
    </parent>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `awk`

```
awk '/parent/,/\/parent/{s=s"\n"$0}/\/modelVersion/{$0=$0s}NR!=FNR' a.xml b.xml
```

or `sed` with temp-file

```
sed -n '/parent/,/\/parent/w part
        1!{
            /^.project/,${
                /\/modelVersion/r part
                p
                          }
           }' a.xml b.xml
```

or with hold-space

```
sed -n '/parent/,/\/parent/H
        1!{
           /^.project/,${
               /\/modelVersion/{
                   G
                   s/\n//
                       }
               p
                         }
           }' a.xml b.xml
```